# UPDATE COM SELECT COMO CONDIÇÃO

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um aplicativo que envia um e-mail para o usuário para confirmar seu email logo quando se cadastra.

Em seguida, tenho duas tabelas no meu banco de dados interno, sendo elas `USUÁRIOS` e `LOGIN`.

Na tabela de `USUÁRIOS` tenho o campo confirmado, que recebe `0` ou `1`:

`0` se o usuário ainda não confirmou seu email.

`1` se o usuário já confirmou seu email.

Na tabela de `LOGIN`, tenho o campo logado, que é usuário que está logado no momento. Digamos que ele já tenha confirmado seu email.
Logo, preciso selecionar o usuário que está logado e atualizar o campo confirmado na tabela de usuários para `1`.

Fiz assim, mas desse jeito ele põe como se todos os usuários já tivessem confirmado seu email:

```
update = "UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1'";

db = getDataBase();
db.transaction (function (tx){
    tx.executeSql (update);
    });
```

Resumindo, eu quero que ele atualize somente o usuário que está logado, ou seja, `logado=1`.

Se alguém puder ajudar.

[image: Tabela Usuários]
[image: Tabela Login]

Comment: Coloque mais informações sobre seu banco de dados, poste a estrutura

Comment: Você não está especificando qual usuario é para mudar para "1", você precisa indicar qual o id do usuario a ser alterado. Ex: `UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' WHERE usuarios.id = 1`

Comment: você precisa passar o codigo do usuario como condição para Update

Comment: Creio que você precisa acrescentar `where logado = 1`.
Veja a resposta já dada e confirme, qual condição precisa, assim a resposta será editada e vc pode aceitar.

Answer (score 1):

O campo `usuario` da segunda tabela é o `id` do **usuario**?

Caso for, você pode fazer assim:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' where usuario in (select id from LOGIN where logado = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar a clausula `WHERE` ao seu SQL para atualizar somente o usuário que você quer. Algo como:

```
update = "UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' WHERE id_usuario = '<usuario_logado>'";
```

Sem o `WHERE` no seu `UPDATE`, todos os registros daquela tabela serão atualizados. É recomendado, inclusive, que não seja feito um `UPDATE` diretamente na tabela sem nenhuma condição `WHERE` (salvo casos específicos);

Comment: Eu não teria que fazer um inner join? Por ter que pegar dados de outra tabela?

Comment: Depende, você vai precisar ter o id daquele usuário que está logado. Por exemplo (conforme as tuas tabelas): `UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' WHERE usuario = '19'"`. Porém, você já deverá ter o id daquele usuário no seu código e passar ele para o seu SQL através de uma variável. Mas se você não quiser utilizar uma variável com o ID, poderá sim fazer um SUBSELECT na tabela `LOGIN` dos usuários logados, porém, irá atualizar todos os usuários que estiverem logados.

Comment: O problema pode ser resolvido com um in: `UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' WHERE usuario in (SELECT usuario FROM login WHERE logado = '1')`. @Tiffany veja se resolve...

Comment: @Melissa ainda não :(

Comment: Como já foi dito, antes de aplicar o `update`, você precisa fazer um `select` na base, provavelmente usando o e-mail cadastrado (ele é único para cada usuário, certo?), para recuperar o usuário logado no momento. Recuperando esse usuário, você terá o `id` dele, que é o que você deve passar, então, no `where` do seu `update`.

Comment: Eu fiz assim mas não acontece nada:

if(data.content.confirmado == 1){ //retorna 1 var emailTeste = data.content.email; // retorna o email certo update = "UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado ='1' WHERE email = 'emailTeste'";

mas o confirmado continua 0.. não atualiza.

Comment: Nesse caso pode ser que ele não esteja entrando dentro do seu `IF`. Já testou se o `UPDATE` está funcionando fora do IF? Ou se o valor da variável emailTeste está correto?

Comment: Está tudo correto. Dei um alert em cada item e apareceu os dados corretamente. Não sei o que pode ser..

Comment: Está ocorrendo algum erro de SQL então? Se não estiver, tente utilizar  `LIKE` ao invés do `=` para comparar com o e-mail. Se ainda não funcionar, precisaria ver seu código e verificar o seu SQL como ele está sendo executado, com o e-mail que está sendo utilizado na comparação.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que fazer um update com join entre a tabela login e a tabela usuario on id da tabela usuario = id da tabela login(id do usuario) ai você da um set a.confirmado = 1 aonde o b.logado(que é a tabela login) seja = 1.

tenta ai e me fala.

update usuario a join login b on a.id_do_usuario = b.id_do_usuario 
set a.confirmado = 1 where b.logado = 1;

VLW abraço

Answer (score 0):

Vou te perguntar de novo! O campo usuario da segunda tabela é chave estrangeira de quem, é do campo id da tabela login? Se não for, sua estrutura das tabelas  está errada.

Sua tabela de login e de usuários deve ter alguma conexão entre elas.

Tabela usuarios:

```
+------------+-------+-------+------------+
| usuario_id | nome  | senha | confirmado | 
+------------+-------+-------+------------+
| 1          | Maria | 1568  | 1          |
+------------+-------+-------+------------+
| 2          | João  | 1234  | 0          |
+------------+-------+-------+------------+
```

tabela login:

```
+----------+--------+------------+
| login_id | logado | usuario_id |
+----------+--------+------------+
| 58       | 1      | 1          |
+----------+--------+------------+
| 59       | 0      | 2          |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

Feito isso é só aplicar o update que postei acima:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' WHERE usuario_id IN(SELECT usuario_id FROM login WHERE logado = 1)
```

Quando você faz o login, você não insere o email da pessoa no formulário?
Você pode fazer o update desta maneira. Desde que sua estrutura esteja correta:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET confirmado = '1' WHERE usuario_id = (SELECT usuario_id FROM login WHERE email= 'tiozinho@gmail.com')
```